# Reading from a file with printer commands and printing in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I'm reading a file and I'm trying to send it to a PCL printer HP LJ2035 with

```
os.startfile("C:/tmp/tmp.txt", "print")
```

That file which I read is encoded in IMB-852 from DOS and has printer commands inside like `^[E^[(17U^[(s10.2H` or `^[(s3B`.

My main issue is here that `os.startfile` prints from Windows on a default printer and it prints also printer commands and doesn't interpret them. The file prints fine when I send it from program writen in Clarion (in DOS) directly to LPT port without Windows printing.

In Linux command `file` on tmp.txt file encoded in IBM-852 returns:

```
tmp.txt: HP PCL printer data
```

How should I read and print that file in Python 3 so that my printer interprets printer commands? Do I need to open that file in `binary` mode? If I do `with open(my_file, 'rb') as f:` I get an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 62: invalid start byte
```